# compiling a Brainfuck hello world program

Tags: brainfuck

I found this weird programming language that is an attempt to create the smallest possible compiler called `brainf*ck`, and i honestly want to try it but i don't have any knowlegde about how to compile the code.
Can you help me compiling a hello world program in `brainf*ck`?

Comment: Brainfuck is usually interpreted, not compiled.  If you found a compiler for it, check its documentation.

Comment: did you read the [taginfo](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/brainfuck/info)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a minimal compiler, surprisingly made by [this guy](https://github.com/alugocp) in [this repository](https://github.com/alugocp/brainfuck).

> I made this interpreter in like 40 minutes. It's under 70 lines of code and it only uses standard libraries in C.
> it can be built by typing

```
make
```

you will get brainfuck.exe

i compiled this brainfuck code
`cat.b`

```
,[.,]
```

using

```
./brainfuck.exe cat.b
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).